# IOS 12 Unwanted communication Reporting Extension Working on Phone but not on Messages app

Tags: ios, swift, ios12

I have been trying to make the new iOS extension Unwanted Communication Reporting work. Currently I couldn't find any good walk-through tutorial or code-sample to make it work. Above that by just firing up a new project with this extension and building it shows me the option of reporting in the Phone App but not on the Messages app, Moreover, the option to enable it only appears in phone app but it says "sms/phone" so I think this should work for both of them.

I know its in beta right now but just want to know if anyone had any luck with it. Also, There is no code to share as its just the boiler plate that comes with the new project.

Comment: Did you manage to get anything working? I find the documentation doesn't match reality, for an example it says "enable the Done button by setting the view controller’s isReadyForClassificationResponse property to true." But there is no sReadyForClassificationResponse property anywhere.

Comment: @Gruntcakes For that you just have to bind a viewController to your extension and then once the view gets loaded your done button will be enabled. (check viewDidLoad there is a line there which is supposed to enable done)

Comment: Hi, what did you set ILClassification ExtensionSMSReportDestination to in the info.plist? I've tried setting it as a string and as a number type, and setting it to a phone number (the documentation says an SMS is sent to whatever is in there). But nothing happens when I hit the Done button (if I report it as junk).

Comment: I am assuming you are stuck at the same place I was. Passing userInfo is mandatory. If you can create a new question I can share with you in detail.

Comment: thank you I appreciate that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675688/how-to-set-contents-of-ilclassificationresponse-when-using-a-unwantedcommunicati

Comment: @tink Have you managed to have something working? Can you share sample code?

Comment: It wasn't working at first but then I re installed iOS and it started working. Can you see your viewer controller firing up? or You can't even see the report message option? Also one thing, I still can't see it on swiping over message thread, but if I long press on a message and select 'more' I can see report message option.

Answer (score 0):

This might have been a personal issue. I reset the whole phone and now I can see the options to report message. Apple might have fixed it in their latest iOS build or it might have just been my device issue.

Comment: Hey @tink, I am having the same problem, I can see report option in recent call of phone app but no report option in message app. Is there any else solution than resetting the phone?

Comment: Hey @tink, Can we customize the text "Report" on the Phone app?

Answer (score -1):

Apple's developer site specifies ”SMS and call spam reporting," which is an app extension that you will have the option of turning on or off.

You may enable an Unwanted Communication extension in the Settings app.   I am not sure if Apple will utilize this but i know for android - screen turns red when such spam calls come in, also caller id notes that but currently apple seems to have found a middle ground.

The following worked for me, you can try:

Remove command definition for this in Plist file.

Delete the Target in project (you can delete code folder).

Comment: Whats this answer supposed to be saying? The OP is asking if anybody has had any success with getting the extension to work, how can deleting the target therefore make it work? What command definition in what Plist file?

Comment: @Ash Im not sure what you are asking me to do.. I am trying to build my app based on this extension, how does deleting the target extension will help me achieve that?