# How to set contents of ILClassificationResponse when using a UnwantedCommunicationReportingExtension?

Tags: ios

If I return anything other than `ILClassificationActionNone` from `UnwantedCommunicationReportingExtension:classificationResponseForRequest` then nothing happens when I click on the Done button (unlike when `ILClassificationActionNone` is returned, and the view controller dismisses).

I've set `ILClassificationExtensionSMSReportDestination` in the info.plist (the documentation doesn't say but I presume the key type if of type String and is a destination number for an SMS).

However it seems like the userInfo of the `ILClassificationResponse` returned from `classificationResponseForRequest` must contain some values. But I can't find any documentation describing what/how userInfo should be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IOS documentation for [SMS/Call Reporting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting/sms_and_call_spam_reporting) they did mention about UserInfo

> .. For ILClassificationActionReportNotJunk or ILClassificationActionReportJunk, the system generates an SMS message based on your response’s action and userInfo properties.

But, It wasn't intuitive that it is a required(kindaa!) field. if userInfo array is undefined the iOS will not create a empty message and hence visually nothing happens.

I have attached my code that takes some additional information from the user and also initiates a new message when done is clicked. I hope this is what you are looking for..

```
    @IBOutlet weak var txtSenderNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textMessage: UITextView!
// Provide a classification response for the classification request
    override func classificationResponse(for request:ILClassificationRequest) -> ILClassificationResponse {

        let userAction:ILClassificationAction =  ILClassificationAction.reportJunk;
        let userData:ILClassificationResponse = ILClassificationResponse.init(action: userAction)
        userData.userInfo = ["sender": self.txtSenderNumber.text, "message": self.textMessage.text]

        return userData
    }
```

Comment: i have just tried same , but unable to open message app after click on 'DONE'

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati this extension doesn't have an adequate error mechanism. It might be crashing when you are pressing done. check device logs, it might give you some hint.

Comment: Thanks for hint! You're right, Extension is getting crashed somehow!Can you please share your code or changes you have made in info.plist?

Comment: can you please tell me how to connect outlet which i have taken in MainInterface.storyboard? as of now I'm changing view controller's class to unwantedcommunicationreportingextension

Comment: instead of userInfo , setting userString worked for me